# В каких случаях конструктор обнуляет поля класса

Tags: c++, конструктор

Не могу найти однозначную информацию по теме обнуления полей класса в конструкторе. Особенно запутывают понятия `тривиальный` и `нетривиальный`.

Допустим, у нас есть класс:

```
class Object
{
    int i;
    Type t;
};
```

В каких случаях `i` и `t` могут остаться неинициализированными после конструирования объекта класса `Object`?

Кто-то говорит, что если для `Object` явно не описан конструктор, то компилятор сгенерирует неявный конструктор по умолчанию, который будет вызывать конструкторы по умолчанию для каждого поля. В этом случае для полей `i` и `t` вызовутся конструкторы по умолчанию. В `i` окажется 0.

Однако, если мы определим свой конструктор, в котором не будем явно вызывать конструкторы полей `i` и `t`, то при вызове такого нашего конструктора поведение будет необычным:

- `i` останется неинициализированным;
- `t` инициализируется конструктором по умолчанию `t::t()`.

Я совершенно запутался:

```
class Type
{
    public:
    Type() : value{0} {}
    int value;
};

class Trivial
{
    public:
    int i;
    Type t;
};

class NotTrivial
{
    public:
    NotTrivial(){}
    int i;
    Type t;
};


void main()
{
    Trivial trivial;
    // Поле i инициализировано 0.
    // Поле t инициализировано.

    NotTrivial notTrivial;
    // Поле i не инициализировано.
    // Поле t инициализировано.
}
```

Comment: поле `i` остается неинициализировано в обоих случаях. Потому что `int` - тип с тривиальным конструктором. Кроме того, класс `Trivial` на самом деле имеет нетривиальный  конструктор, как и `NotTrivial`. Ну тут есть и принципиальная ошибка - по значению, хранящемуся в переменной, нельзя судить, была ли эта переменная инициализирована или нет.

Comment: То есть, для элементарных типов конструкторы по умолчанию не вызываются, если мы не вызываем их явно? Такое происходит только с элементарными типами `int`, `float` и пр.? Или же это свойство всех `POD` типов?

Comment: У этих типов тривиальный конструктор, то бишь вызывать нечего.

Comment: Теперь я запутался еще больше...

Comment: Чтобы не запутываться, надо помнить, что в С++ есть правило - не делать никаких действий не заказанных программистом. Обнуление полей это действие, которое занимает время и ресурсы. Поэтому никто не обнуляет даже поля целых ни в каких классах, пока программист не напишет явно конструктор, в котором обнулит поля.

Comment: Окей, про простые типы понятно. А для простых структур (`like C`) конструктор по умолчанию так же является тривиальным и ничего не делает?

Comment: Если есть конструктор с параметрами для поля класса, то он вызывается. Но надо написать его вызов и передать ему параметры. Если есть конструктор без параметров для поля класса, то он вызывается без параметров . Если конструктора нет, то ничего не вызывается. Считайте, что для встроенных типов конструкторов (обнуляющих или объединичивающих или еще как-то инициализирующих переменные этих типов) нет.

Comment: Чтобы это определить существует трейт `std::is_trivially_constructible`

Comment: Конструктор без параметров это не то же самое, что отсутствие конструктора. Если конструктор без параметров для класса есть, то он вызывается при конструировании объекта класса без параметров. Если для класса нет никакого конструктора, то ничего не вызывается при конструировании объекта класса. И все поля объекта такого класса остаются не инициализированными, то есть заполненными мусором.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> В каких случаях конструктор обнуляет поля класса

Только в тех случаях, когда

- вы сами явно ручками написали конструктор для вашего класса и сами прописали в нем обнуление полей вашего класса, или
- вы в определении класса явно указали обнуляющий инициализатор для данного нестатического поля.

В С++ существуют другие механизмы обнуления полей класса, но они не имеют никакого отношения к конструкторам и работают "в обход" конструкторов. Например, таким механизмом является value-initialization для классов без пользовательского конструктора.

В вашем примере с `class Object` конструктор данного класса неявно генерируется компилятором и никакого обнуления поля `i` ни в коем случае не делает. Однако к этому классу можно извне применить value-initialization и тем самым вызвать обнуление поля `i`

```
{
  Object t;   // `t.i` содержит мусор
  Object u{}; // `u.i` содержит 0
}
```

Обратите внимание, еще раз, что в данном примере обнуление `u.i` не является результатом работы конструктора, а является следствием совершенно постороннего процесса - value-initialization.